# PHP Load data infile only works for root

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a PHP script to import a csv file into a MySQL table using LOAD DATA INFILE. The query works for both the root user and non root user from within MySQL, however when running the query from the PHP script it only works for the root user.

I'm fairly sure that I have all the permissions set up correctly and have even tested by giving the non root user full permissions.

Is there anything i'm missing that could prevent the user from running the query?

Here is the script:

```
$files = scandir('/var/www/html/imports/pigsback/');

foreach($files as $file) {
    if ($file != '.' && $file != '..') {
        $import = 
            "LOAD DATA INFILE '/var/www/html/imports/pigsback/$file'
            IGNORE INTO TABLE pigsback.temp_import
            FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'
            LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
            IGNORE 1 LINES
            (@deal_id, @voucher_headline, @item_sku, @purchase_date, @first_name, @last_name, @address_1, @address_2,
            @address_3, @address_4, @postcode, @region, @phone, @delivery_note, @sequence_id, @deal_price, @country)
            SET deal_id=@deal_id, voucher_headline=@voucher_headline, item_sku=@item_sku, purchase_date=@purchase_date, 
            first_name=@first_name, last_name=@last_name, address_1=@address_1,address_2=@address_2, address_3=@address_3, 
            address_4=@address_4, postcode=@postcode, region=@region, phone=@phone, delivery_note=@delivery_note, 
            sequence_id=@sequence_id, deal_price=@deal_price, country=@country";

        if(! mysqli_query($connect, $import)) {
            echo 'Failed: ' . $file . PHP_EOL;
        }
        else {

        }
    }
}
```